# Titanium not updating TableViewSection with new rows

Tags: ios, titanium, titanium-alloy

Since I updated my app to latest sdk version my `TableViewSection`'s no longer seem to be updating with new rows.

Here is my view:

```
<Alloy>
    <Tab id="customers" title="Customers" icon="glyphicons/glyphicons/png/glyphicons_003_user.png">
        <Window id="customers_window" title="Customers">
            <RightNavButton>
                <Button id="add">Add</Button>
            </RightNavButton>
            <TableView id="table" filterAttribute="title">
                <SearchBar platform="android,ios"/>
                <TableViewSection id="customers_list"></TableViewSection>
            </TableView>
        </Window>
    </Tab>
</Alloy>
```

Here is my contoller:

```
...
function customersCallback (customers, callback) {

    // throw those into globals so we can use them again
    Alloy.Globals.customers = customers;

    // empty list first
    $.customers_list.rows = [];

    customers.forEach(function(customer) {
        Ti.API.info(customer);

        var payload = {
            customer : customer
        };
        var row=Alloy.createController('customer_row',payload).getView();
        $.customers_list.add(row);
    });

    // tell async we're finished
    callback(null);
};
...
```

I read somewhere that you can now use `appendRow` for when the `TableViewSection` has been rendered. However when I try to use that I get:

> 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating
>   '$.customers_list.appendRow(row)') at customers.js (line 11)

Is there anyway I can force and update? Or get access to `appendRow`?

**Titanium SDK 3.2.0 GA**

**Deploying to iOS simulator v7**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the documentation, your customer_list is a TableViewSection and appendRow doesn't appear to be a function.  For the TableViewSection, you use the function 'add' has these comments:

> Adds a table view row to this section.
>
> Should be called before adding the section to a table. Calling add on
>   a section that's already been added to a table does not update the
>   table.
>
> To add a row to a section after it's been added to a table, call one
>   of the TableView methods, insertRowBefore, insertRowAfter, or
>   appendRow.
>
> On Android, it is possible to update a section by adding or removing
>   rows and then resetting the table view's data property. However, this
>   approach is not portable and is not recommended.

http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.UI.TableViewSection-method-add

I couldn't find any specific example of this being accomplished without using the method they say to avoid in the documentation,
[How to append a row to a TableViewSection in Titanium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2721705/how-to-append-a-row-to-a-tableviewsection-in-titanium)

Comment: Using ```appendRow()``` on the TableView works. Though I don't know how it knows which TableViewSection to add it too?

Comment: Did you have any row 'selected' when you tried your add procedure?  In the documentation it talked about using an index.